# I need to hook a cascading save in playframework 1.x

Tags: hibernate, playframework-1.x

I need to figure out how to hook saves that cascade into a particular class extending model in playframework 1.x.  I need the hook so I can execute a piece of code that will recalculate a data field on the object prior to persistence using data that ultimately comes from data fields belonging to model objects of other classes that cascade into the object.

The actual process started by .save() seems to be very resistant to hooking.  I was unable to hook on the saveAndCascade() and creating a setWillBeSaved() method did not provide a hook either even though the playframework documentation seems to suggest that it should.

I have a solution, but it seems to be a rather "bad" solution that involves a hack to trick hibernate into writing when it shouldn't have to.

The hack solution is to add a "hack" boolean field to the object and toggle the field every time the object is loaded, persisted or updated.  This is to make it so that it is never clean.

This is done because the only hook that I've been able to find so far is a method annotated with @PrePersist and @PreUpdate.  The problem is that hibernate will not call the annotated method if it does not believe the object is dirty.  Which creates the problem when a data field changes in one of the related objects that cascades into the object in question that should prompt a recalculation that would make the clean object dirty, but the recalculation does not happen because hibernate thinks the object is clean.

Here is a simple version of the solution I am using (holy buckets is adding 4 spaces annoying).  Persisting any one of the below objects results in object A being persisted with the correct value of a.

```
@Entity
public class A extends Model
{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();
    private Integer a = 0;
    private Boolean hack = true;

    //algorithm that only matters to the question so far as it uses data fields from B and C.
    public Integer getA()
    {
        Integer returnValue = 0;

        for(B b : bList)
        {
            returnValue = returnValue + b.getB();

            for(C c : b.getCList())
            {
                returnValue = returnValue + c.getC();
            }
        }

    return  returnValue;
    }

    public void setBList(List<B> bList)
    {
        this.bList = bList;
    }

    public List<B> getBList()
    {
        return bList;
    }

    //Hibernate will not call this method if it believes the object to be clean.
    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    private void recalculateA()
    {
        hack = !hack; //remove the dirt and cross our fingers that hibernate won't write if the object is no longer dirty.
        a = getA(); //recalculate the value of A, reflecting the changes made in the objects cascading into A.
    }

    //Hack to put dirt on every clean object to force hibernate to call recalculateA whenever someone tries to save A.
    @PostPersist
    @PostUpdate
    @PostLoad
    private void hack()
    {
        hack = !hack;
    }

}
```

-

```
@Entity
public class B extends Model
{
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private A a;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b",  cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<C> cList = new ArrayList<C>();

    private Integer b = 0;

    public List<C> getCList()
    {
        return cList;
    }

    public void setCList(List<C> cList)
    {
        this.cList = cList;
    }

    public void setA(A a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void setB(Integer b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Integer getB()
    {
        return b;
    }
```

### }

```
@Entity
public class C extends Model
{
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private B b;

    private Integer c = 0;

    public C(Integer c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public Integer getC()
    {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(Integer c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void setB(B b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

My "there has to be a better way to do this" senses are tingling greatly.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the save method on the root object you save and call your calculation method from there.

For me, hiding a business calculation into the persistence process is not a good thing because you ensure that it is called everytime but you hide this into a process that needs technical knowledge.

Explicitly calling this calculation method through some sort of "calculateAndSave" method makes it clearer.

Comment: Overriding the save() doesn't help with the cascade, since save() is not called during the cascade to other objects and the method that is called is private.  Putting the business calculation into the persistence process is less than ideal, however it is a case of existing code making it seem like a candidate for the least worst fix.

Comment: using a save method on a root object is possible if you always save your leaf entity through this root object. If your persistence path are multiples and can vary over the time then this solution is not the best.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to force hibernate to get the a value through the getA method

```
@Entity
public class A extends Model
{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();
    @Transient
    private Integer a = 0;
    private Boolean calculated = false;

    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public Integer getA()
    {
        if (!calculated) {
            Integer returnValue = 0;

            for(B b : bList)
            {
                returnValue = returnValue + b.getB();

                for(C c : b.getCList())
                {
                    returnValue = returnValue + c.getC();
                }
            }

            a = returnValue;
            calculated = true;
        }
        return a;
    }

    public void setBList(List<B> bList)
    {
        this.bList = bList;
        calculated = false;
    }

    public List<B> getBList()
    {
        return bList;
    }
}
```

But this means you can invalidate the calculated flag each time the source of the calculation change, this may be difficult when the cList of the b object change.

If your calculation is not so heavy you can also avoid the calculated flag and redo it each time getA is called this is the simplest solution but not the most performant